# Is it possible to extend Dublin Core Ontology to contain other metadata for artefacts?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, dublin-core

I want to know how to extend (if possible) the current Dublin Core Metadata Set  to include  other types of Metadata characterizing resources on a technical level.

Looking at [DCMI Vocab](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#elements-type) I realized there is the DCMI "Type" where it is mentioned that it helps "To describe the file format, physical medium, or dimensions of the resource, use the Format element"

Allow me kindly to explain further what is needed here: 
In a web-based virtual museum, videos, audios, images, 3D models, Spherical images (Photospheres) or Videospheres etc... are fetched to different clients of different hardware capabilities(tablets, PCs, mobile). 
Suppose we have a video, I need to store metadata that characterize the resource itself like Frame Rate, or Bit rate, or compression codec, Size on disk etc... 
For a 3D model per example, I might store the Number of Vertices/ number of faces, Resolution of textures, Size on Disk among many others etc... things of that sort for each type of resource. Obviously those metadata differ for each resource type. You probably guessed why this help! To fetch to the right client (depending on its capability) the right resource resolution etc...

The idea is to be able to store as much "characterizing" metadata as it is deemed necessary for each resource (Image, audio, video, 3D model etc...) together with the traditional metadata that come with Dublin Core.

I want to be able to store those metadata so that my application -in this case  a web-based virtual museum - would retrieve those  metadata with the actual artefacts and then do the right decision.

Probably others have done the extension for other ontological domains. 
I read couple of academic papers about this but these papers don't explain how they managed to extend DC on a practical level (Programmatically) and to tell you the truth even on an abstract level.

Can you kindly guide me in the right directions, point me to some useful resources that can help both on a practical level and on an abstract level?
Maybe Dublin Core is not the right ontology to extend??

Thanks so much for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Have you look at [schema.org](http://schema.org/ImageObject) (or rather its [OWL version](http://topbraid.org/schema/))? Or you can create and publish your own ontology, declaring some of properties to be subproperties of DC etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think Dublin Core (neither Elements nor Terms) has the proper expressivity for your use case. If you're looking for vocabularies or ontologies for a specific use case, a good place to start is [LOV](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/) (Linked Open Vocabularies) where you can search for vocabulary terms. A [search for 'video format'](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=Video%20format) gives a hint that the [EBUCore data model](https://tech.ebu.ch/publications/tech3293) from the European Broadcasting Union might be something you would want to look more closely at.